# jQuery live filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, livesearch

I'm doing a live filter using jQuery. You can select the elements which have the string in their names or/and the elements filtering by location and/or activity. That's the idea. With my script is working ok but in separate mode. I'd like to join all the filters in just one match. How could I do it? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function (){
                jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
                    return function( elem ) {
                        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                    };
                });
                $("input").keyup(function(){
                            $(this).change();     
                });
                $("input").change(function(){
                            var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                            if(filter) {
                                 $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find('a:Contains(' + filter + ')').parent();
                                  $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                                   $matches.slideDown();
                            }else{
                                 $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li").slideDown();
                            }
                            return false;
                });
                $("#location").change(function(){
                    var filter = $(this).val();
                    if(filter != 'default') {
                        $matches = $('#list_pr').find("li a[alt*="+filter+"]").parent();
                         $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                         $matches.slideDown();
                    }else{
                         $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li").slideDown();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                $("#category").change(function(){
                    var filter = $(this).val();
                    alert(filter);
                    if(filter != 'default') {
                        $matches = $('#list_pr').find("li a[alt*="+filter+"]").parent();
                         $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                         $matches.slideDown();
                    }else{
                         $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li").slideDown();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to modify your code but here is an idea for you:

```
function filterByText(arrayToFilter, filterValue) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToFilter.length; ++i) {
        if ( /* arrayToFilter[i] matches criteria */ ) {
            result.push(arrayToFilter[i]);
        } 
    }
    return result;
}

function filterByLocation(arrayToFilter, filterValue) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToFilter.length; ++i) {
        if ( /* arrayToFilter[i] matches criteria */ ) {
            result.push(arrayToFilter[i]);
        } 
    }
    return result;
}

function filterByCategory(arrayToFilter, filterValue) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToFilter.length; ++i) {
        if ( /* arrayToFilter[i] matches criteria */ ) {
            result.push(arrayToFilter[i]);
        } 
    }
    return result;
}

function filter() {
    var result [];
    var listItems = $('#my_list li');
    var filterValue = $('#filter_input').val();

    result = filterByText(listItems, filterValue);

    if (/* filter by location is enabled */) {
        result = filterByLocation(result, filterValue);
    }
    if (/* filter by category is enabled */) {
        result = filterByCategory(result, filterValue);
    }

    // Present filtered items

    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; ++i) {
        if (result.indexOf(listItems[i]) > -1) {
            listItems[i].show(); // or .slideUp();
        } else {
            listItems[i].hide(); // or .slideDown();
        }
    }
}

$('#location, #category, input').change(function() {
    filter();
});
```

Of course, there is plenty of room for optimization there, but still, that is just an "idea" as a said earlier.

Comment: Hello, firstly thank you for your idea. I will try to explain a little more about my weird script. It's a shop database. Category and location are select, so I have an input text (to filter by name or just a part of it), and two select (to filter by location and/or activity). The information about the selects are in the 'alt' attr. As I posted it's working perfectly. (follow in another comment)

Comment: The problem is i.e. if I'm filtering Beauty Shops (category) in New York (location) it loads firstly the Beauty Shops and then the Shops at New York, instead of the Beauty Shops at New York. My idea would be accumulate the marches in one var (as .= in php) and then hide them or show them... Is that possible in jQuery?

Comment: You can always concatenate the results by using javascript's .concat() and then use jquery's .show()/.hide() functions on the HTML elements. Let me update the answer to tell you what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I have the script working!!!!!!!
Now, I should work on optimization... any idea?? :)
Thank you!!!!!!

```
$(document).ready(function (){
                jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
                    return function( elem ) {
                        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                    };
                });
                $("input").keyup(function(){
                        $(this).change();     
                });
                $("input, #provincia, #categoria").change(function(){
                    var filter1 = $("input").val().toLowerCase();
                    var filter2 = $("#provincia").val().toLowerCase().replace(" ","-");
                    var filter3 = $("#categoria").val().toLowerCase().split("/");
                    filter3 = filter3[0];

                    if(filter1 != '' && filter1 != 'nombre del comercio'){
                        if(filter2 != 'default' && filter3 == 'default'){
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter1+"][title*="+filter2+"]").parent();
                        }else if(filter2 == 'default' && filter3 != 'default'){
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter1+"][title*="+filter3+"]").parent();
                        }else if(filter2 != 'default' && filter3 != 'default'){
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter1+"][title*="+filter2+"][title*="+filter3+"]").parent();   
                        }else{
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter1+"]").parent();
                        }
                        $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                        $matches.slideDown();

                    }else if(filter2 != 'default'){
                        if(filter3 != 'default'){
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter2+"][title*="+filter3+"]").parent();
                        }else{
                            $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter2+"]").parent();
                        }
                        $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                        $matches.slideDown();
                    }else if(filter3 != 'default'){
                        $matches = $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li a[title*="+filter3+"]").parent();

                        $('li', '#list_pr, #list_ba').not($matches).slideUp();
                        $matches.slideDown();
                    }else{
                        $('#list_pr, #list_ba').find("li").slideDown();

                    }
                    return false;
                });
    });
```